# How to pass null values to pojo properties to get converted into Json using Jackson and Spring AOP is also used

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-aop

I am trying to return a json in spring using Jackson jar. But i am getting error while converting the same. The error is something related to Spring AOP because when i removed that the code is working fine. Please find the pojo details below:-

```
//@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
 @JsonInclude(content=JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) 
 public class UserBean {

   private String result;
   private String tID;

  //getters and setters

}
```

I have tried both the above annotation at class level.

In the above code i am only setting the value in TID field and result field has the default value as null. There is a ToString method also in this java class.

Controller Class :-

```
@Autowired
public UserBean userBean;

userBean.settID("T123456");
```

pom.xml->

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" />` is set in spring-servlet.xml

Application-context.xml has the following entry:-

```
<bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
<bean name="jsonTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
```

I have also written the AOP class and modified all the 5 methods namely :`@After`,`@Before`,`@Around`,`@AfterThrowing`,`@AfterReturning`.

```
public class LogginAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogginAspect.class);

    @After("execution(* com.fca.c2pc..*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        logger.info("After executing method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        logger.info("***************************************************************************");
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.fca.c2pc..*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        logger.info("***************************************************************************");
        logger.info("Before executing method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Around("execution(* com.fca.c2pc..*.*(..))")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object clazz = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getName();
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info("Entering Class " + clazz + " With Method Name " + methodName);
        Object[] obj = pjp.getArgs();
        int i = 0;
        try {
            for (Object o : obj) {
                logger.info(++i + " : Parameter Name :" + (null != o ? o.toString() : ""));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Object output = pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs());

        logger.info("Excecution Completed for method : " + methodName + " in Class : " + clazz + " with result "
                + output);
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        logger.info("Execution time for method : " + methodName + " in Class : " + clazz + " : " + elapsedTime
                + " milliseconds.");
        return output;
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.fca.c2pc..*.*(..))", throwing = "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {

        logger.info("Exception thrown by method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        logger.info("Exception name : " + error);
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.fca.c2pc..*.*(..))", returning = "result")
    public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

        logger.info("Method : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " returned value is : " + result);
    }
```

This is the error i get ->

```
 Could not write content: 
    No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.TrueClassFilter
    and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
    (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) 
    (through reference chain: com.fca.c2pc.bean.UserBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c56dc6af
["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.interceptor.["pointcut"]->
   org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut["classFilter"]); 
   nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.TrueClassFilter and 
   no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
   (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) 
   (through reference chain: com.fca.c2pc.bean.UserBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c56dc6af
["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.interceptor.["pointcut"]->
   org.springframework.aop.TruePointcut["classFilter"])
```

Comment: Why is your `UserBean` even a spring managed bean?

Comment: Then what it should be?? And how does that matter with the exception i am getting.

Comment: Only spring beans have AOP applied, if it isn't a spring bean it won't be enriched with AOP hence that should eliminate your error. Not everything has to be a spring bean...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But for example my UserBean class has a some reference of other class or some service that needs to be registered with spring container. Then what should be changed in  the code to make the above code work.

Comment: Why would you expose application beans as JSON, you should expose resources...

Comment: You mean the service and Dao class should be exposed and all other beans/pojo should be handled through application ??

Comment: No resources as in for instance a User...Not your UserService etc. those are application beans you want to hide those.